# VBA program getting slow

Tags: excel, filesystems, vba

I am running this program to convert 1.5 million '.tab' format files into excel. Initially this program working fine but subsequently its speed slowing down. I tried this on several system, all behaving similarly. Also I tried to clear temp files, drive cleanup but worthless. What should I do to make it efficient?

```
Sub runFiles()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fldr As Object

Dim fldrPath As String
Dim i As Double
Dim wb As Workbook

fldrPath = "C:\Users\skumar150\Desktop\upwork data\RAW\ACS"
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(fldrPath)

i = 551

For Each fl In fldr.Files
    i = i + 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fldr.Path & "\" & fl.Name)
    createFile "C:\Users\skumar150\Desktop\upwork data\Excel Data1\ACS3",   wb, i 
    Set wb = Nothing
    fl.Delete

 Next fl
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function createFile(fldrPath As String, ByRef wb1 As Workbook, vr As Double)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim flName As String, fldrName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim delrow As Integer
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = Worksheets(wb.Sheets(1).Name)


wb1.Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("a1")
fname = wb1.Name
wb1.Close False

With wb
    With ws
        .Names.Add "countyID", ws.Range("b2").Value
        .Names.Add "Title", ws.Range("b3").Value
        .Names.Add "rate_per", ws.Range("b4").Value
        .Names.Add "topic", ws.Range("b5").Value
        .Names.Add "yLabel", ws.Range("b6").Value
        delrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("METADATA END", .Range("a:a"), 0)
        .Rows("1:" & delrow).Delete
    End With
    .Close True, fldrPath & "\__sk" & vr & "_" & fname & ".xlsx"

End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably requires in depth investigation with access to the environment.
However few points:

1) Is the number of files (1.5 mln) is constant? Just to ensure, that decrease in performance is not caused by number of iterations. (Why i = 551?)

2) Can you avoid using: ".Rows("1:" & delrow).Delete"? Such range operations have impact on overall performance.

3) Try to put some timers in the code to measure how long it takes to ie. save the Excel file. If 90% of runtime is caused by file save it may be network issue (if you are running on corporate network).